# WordPress links to social icons not linking

Tags: php, wordpress, buddypress

I'm attempting to add social follow icons to a BuddyPress site using a section of code that I found here:
https://buddypress.org/support/topic/display-users-social-follow-buttons-in-profile/

I followed the suggestion downthread and added the code to a bp-custom.php file in my plugins directory and the icons are showing up where they should but the link to the social profile is showing as text and when I click on the link it returns a 404 page.

I'm sure I have something wrong but I'm just too <strike>clueless</strike> new to spot it.

```
<?php
//Social Media Icons based on the profile user info
function member_social_extend(){
    $dmember_id = $bp->displayed_user->id;
    $fb_info = xprofile_get_field_data('facebook', $dmember_id);
    $google_info = xprofile_get_field_data('googleplus', $dmember_id);
    $linkedin_info = xprofile_get_field_data('linkedin', $dmember_id);
    $twitter_info = xprofile_get_field_data('twitter', $dmember_id);
    echo '<div class="member-social">';
    if($fb_info||$google_info||$linkedin_info||$twitter_info){
        echo 'My Social: ';
    }

    if ($fb_info) {
    ?>
    <span class="fb-info"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/<?php echo $fb_info; ?>"  title="My Facebook" target="_blank"><img src="<?php bloginfo('wpurl'); ?>/wp-content/themes/family-openstrap-child/images/facebook.png" /></a></span>
<?php
}
    ?>
    <?php
    if ($google_info) {
    ?>
    <span class="google-info"><a href="https://profiles.google.com/<?php echo $google_info; ?>" title="My Googleplus" target="_blank"><img src="<?php bloginfo('wpurl'); ?>/wp-content/themes/family-openstrap-child/images/googleplus.png" /></a></span>
<?php
}
    ?>
    <?php
    if ($linkedin_info) {
    ?>
    <span class="linkedin-info"><a href="https://www.linkedin.com/<?php echo $linkedin_info; ?>" title="My LinkedIn" target="_blank"><img src="<?php bloginfo('wpurl'); ?>/wp-content/themes/family-openstrap-child/images/linkedin.png" /></a></span>
<?php
}
    ?>
    <?php
    if ($twitter_info) {
    ?>
    <span class="twitter-info"><a href="https://twitter.com/<?php echo $twitter_info; ?>" title="My Twitter" target="_blank" class="twitter-follow-button""><img src="<?php bloginfo('wpurl'); ?>/wp-content/themes/family-openstrap-child/images/twitter.png" /></a></span>
<?php
}
echo '</div>';
}
add_filter( 'bp_before_member_header_meta', 'member_social_extend' );
?>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you show the URL that gives you a 404?

Comment: Yes, here. http://stewartvillage.com/members/sandy/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like `xprofile_get_field_data()` creates its own `<a>` tag, so you don't have to write one out like you've done there. Try this instead:

```
$fb_info = xprofile_get_field_data(
    '<img src="' . bloginfo('wpurl') . '/wp-content/themes/family-openstrap-child/images/facebook.png" />',
    $dmember_id
);
...
<span class="fb-info"><?php echo $fb_info; ?></span>
```

Not sure if `xprofile_get_field_data()` will let you pass HTML in the first parameter there, so if that doesn't work quite right, you could fall back to something simpler (no image) like:

```
$fb_info = xprofile_get_field_data('Facebook', $dmember_id);
```

Comment: That solved part of my problem, the links are at least correctly resolving now. Any idea why I'm seeing text there instead of what should just be a icon that links to a social media site?

Comment: I'd guess it's just something about how `xprofile_get_field_data()` behaves. I did some work with BuddyPress a few years back and remember the documentation being pretty scarce, so this is probably as helpful as I get :-/